# Show NavigationController in UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UICollectionView from the Cell it comes to another UIViewController with a Zoom Animation. I have to Embed it with a UINavigationController but when it start in the Simulator it don´t Show a UINavigationController. What is the Problem ? 
Thanks for Help.

[Screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhitn.png)

```
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    let cell: PhotoCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)as! PhotoCell

    let detailViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FullPhotoController") as! FullPhotoController
    let attributes = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    let attributesFrame = attributes?.frame
    let frameToOpenFrom = collectionView.convertRect(attributesFrame!, toView: collectionView.superview)
    transitionDelegate.openingFrame = frameToOpenFrom

    let picture = everypicture[indexPath.row]
    detailViewController.currentpicture = picture
    detailViewController.transitioningDelegate = transitionDelegate
    detailViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom


    presentViewController(detailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

Comment: is "FullPhotoController" a UINavigationController? if not you are just presenting a regular modal controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reference a ViewController from a Storyboard using StoryboardId it ignores any navigation views it may be embedded in. So you will have to do something like the below. I have omitted some of your setup code for brevity.

```
let detailViewController: UIViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FullPhotoController") as! FullPhotoController
let navigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: detailViewController)
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
navigationController.transitioningDelegate = transitionDelegate

self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: when i make that i have a NavigationController but then the Animation is not a zoom Animation, the Animation is a Show Detail (e.g.Replace). What can i do there ?

Comment: Guessing the zoom is handled by modalPresentationStyle = .Custom and transitioningDelegate = transitionDelegate? If so just do what you did on the detailViewController but apply it to the navigationController. I will update the answer.

Comment: If that was the correct answer please mark it as answered and up vote.